# Double timezone. How to delete one?

Tags: time

After upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, my clock was always one hour fast. I issued the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

```
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Brussels'
Local time is now:      Mon Dec 30 11:52:06 CET 2013.
Universal Time is now:  Mon Dec 30 10:52:06 UTC 2013.
```

The time is correct now, but I notice a double time-zone in the clock-applet. How can I remove the other one?

[image]

Note that cat `/etc/timezone` returns Europe/Brussels. The Copenhagen-entry isn't specified. However if one clicks on the clock-applet on the Brussels-value, the
Brussels-value disappears and only the Copenhagen-entry is left. Now this
entry appears in `/etc/timezone`.

Answer (score 1):

Install *dconf Editor*.

Select *com -> canonical -> indicator -> datetime*

The field **show-auto-detected-location** was set.
After untagging this field, both timezones were no longer displayed

[image]